# Convert string to list of DTOs

Tags: java, json, jackson, mapping

I have a simple DTO:

```
public class DtoParamField {
    private String name;
    private Object value;

    private DtoParamField(String name, Object value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
```

I expect that it would be received as JSON like this:

```
{
    "field1": "value1",
    "field2": "field2",
    "params": [{name="1", value="123"}, {name="2", value="123"}]
}
```

What would be the fastest and easiest way to map a `params` property a list of `DToParamField`?

Comment: *I have a simple DTO*
You don't. You have a *field*. The clue is in the name. A DTO is made up of fields. All decent JSON APIs have the ability to map to real objects in your problem domain. You should use one of them.

Comment: What tool you're using to work with JSON?

Comment: Jackson (object mapper)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understood correctly, you're interested only in the data contained in the JSON-array `params`.

You can address the problem in the following steps:

- Extract `JsonNode` that correspond to `params` property in the JSON input. For that, you can use [`ObjectMapper.readTree()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectMapper.html#readTree(java.lang.String)) and apply `get()` to obtain a specific node from a tree.
- Then parse the `JsonNode` into a list List. For that you can make use of [`ObjectReader.readValue()`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-databind/javadoc/2.7/com/fasterxml/jackson/databind/ObjectReader.html#readValue(com.fasterxml.jackson.databind.JsonNode)).

That's how it might look like:

```
String myJson = """
    {
        "field1":"value1",
        "field2":"field2",
        "params":[
            {
                "name":"1",
                "value":"123"
            },
            {
                "name":"2",
                "value":"123"
            }
        ]
    }
    """;
        
ObjectMapper mapper = new ObjectMapper();
JsonNode node = mapper.readTree(myJson).get("params");
    
ObjectReader reader = mapper.readerFor(new TypeReference<List<DtoParamField>>() {});
List<DtoParamField> params = reader.readValue(node);
        
params.forEach(System.out::println);
```

*Output:*

```
Test.DtoParamField(name=1, value=123)
Test.DtoParamField(name=2, value=123)
```

***Note*** that in order to construct your DTO instances successefully Jackson would need either:

- *Setters* and *no-args constructor* provided withing the `DtoParamField` class .
- Or, you would need to apply some data-binding annotations on the to make the existing *all-args constructor* eligible to be used by Jackson, specifically [`@JsonCreator`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.9/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonCreator.html) on the constractor and [`@JsonProperty`](https://fasterxml.github.io/jackson-annotations/javadoc/2.6/com/fasterxml/jackson/annotation/JsonProperty.html) on each argument. This approach allows having `final` fields (which is not possible with setters).

Creating *setters* and *no-args constructor* is trivial, that's how the latter option would look like:

```
public static class DtoParamField {
    private String name;
    private Object value;
    
    @JsonCreator
    private DtoParamField(
        @JsonProperty("name") String name,
        @JsonProperty("value") Object value) {
        this.name = name;
        this.value = value;
    }
    
    // getters, etc.
}
```

Also note that in order to serialize `DtoParamField` into JSON (*if needed*), you would need getters.

Comment: There is one caveat - I don't get json in the params field. Its array of objects

Comment: @EvgeniyZelenskiy You mean *json **with** the `params` field*. OK, then specify please the target property can be identified with the JSON input? Would be it the only array in your JSON? Please add the clarification to the question and notify me by leaving a comment.

Comment: @EvgeniyZelenskiy Did you managed to clarify your requirements? There are many ways to examine JSON-input, but you need to know what you're looking for.